# Why does this program get deadlock?

Tags: c++, deadlock

I Have following piece of code that sometimes produces deadlock, sometimes not. Why does this happen?  I closed input stream for the child process after starting reading output from him.

```cpp
{       
        boost::process::ipstream out;
        boost::process::ipstream err;
        boost::process::opstream in;
        boost::process::child ch("/home/ivan/CLionProjects/BoostPractise/build/Boost.Test.sort",
                                 boost::process::std_in < in,
                                 boost::process::std_out > out,
                                 boost::process::std_err > err);
        in << dataSet.size();
        std::for_each(dataSet.begin(),dataSet.end(),
                      [&](int el){in << el << ' ';});

        in.close();

        auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        ch.wait_for(std::chrono::duration(std::chrono::seconds(TIME_LIMIT)));
}
```

Comment: link to a little bit fuller code: https://pastebin.com/rkWqQSct

Comment: please provide a [mre]. At a guess the program attempts to output more to the stdout/stderr streams than their buffers can acommodate